# Unable to use the infinite scroll feature of ui grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to follow this example to implement infinite scrolling: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/212_infinite_scroll

But I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at new 
>   (ui-grid.js:2559) Cannot read property 'infiniteScroll' of undefined
>   (myApp)

I have already added:  `angular.module('app', ['ngTouch','ui.grid','ui.grid.infiniteScroll']);`
and `ui-grid-infinite-scroll directive` in my html.

Is there any thing else that is missing?

Comment: do you also have to require ui.bootstrap in your project?

Comment: Where is `myApp` defined?

Comment: Yes, both are taken care of.

Comment: Can we see all your source code?